# Can we dump data in HF-RFID card through android app without using any external hardware?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I need to write a user's ref id to the HF-RFID card through the android application so that once I scan it I can get the user of that card. So is it possible to do such thing without using external hardware.

Comment: If you getting the solution can you please post the answer here.